# Image Pixel values

Tags: matlab

I want to get a decimal values of pixel of certain grayscale image but here i require say decimal values of first 20 pixel only..(1,1) to (1,20)

I know there is pixval command available in MATLAB but it's not easy to get values of pixels

like

(1,1)
(1,2)
(1,3) etc

Need adjustment of mouse over image

Any help is appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MATLAB, an image is just a matrix. So accessing pixels is the same as accessing matrix elements.

For example:

```
im = imread('someimage.jpg');

firstrow = im(1,:);
firstcol = im(:,1);
first20pixels = im(1:20);
```

I have no idea what you mean by "need adjustment of mouse over image".

Comment: pixval command turns on interactive display of information about image pixels , need to rotate mouse over image to get perticular pixel information